# error opening dashDB

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

After I have added a service dashDB to my Bluemix application and I click on it, I got in IE11 this message:
 The website declined to show this webpage
 HTTP 403

When I did the same in the Google crome I got a square head which looked sad.
Does anyone know what to do?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with "click on it"? Is this the "launch" button? Is the service already provisioned?

Comment: @Karin : Are you on Corporate network with strict firewall rules?  Please note that dashDB dashboard https port is : 8443 . I wonder if your network configuration blocking https traffic on that port ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Yes I am in Corporate network so I will try to look into if there is something blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information to go but I would suggest the following to narrow down the cause of the problem or resolve the issue:
- verify that service has been provisioned successfully (unless it's an existing instance that is known to work in the past)
- clear browser cache/restart to eliminate any transient issues
- BlueMix status page (https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) is currently reporting some authentication issues which potentially could cause problem, it should be check if the 403 error is still reported after the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth to create the service with the "leave unbound" option and try to click on it. After you could bind it to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if the dashDB instance is up or not by accessing the https_url from the VCAP variable associated with the dashDB instance (for e.g.: https://bluemix05.bluforcloud.com:8443)  and provide your username and password (also from the VCAP variable) for that instance and see if you can log in.